# Extract real IP behind Load Balancer on .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, ip

I was recently to implement a new feature which requires users' IP Address.

Even though I have searched a lot i couldn't find or understand the way of doing what i am about to explain (shouldn't be that hard I guess, but I'm really new to the whole IT thing).

So the case is that I need to get  the users real ip address in order to save it on a local db log file. Its a .net mvc application that uses HTTPS on the most part and the problem is the load balancer that sits in front of the actual servers. From what i have found so far (correct me if i am wrong) you need to decrypt the packet (at the load balancer stage), get the real IP, then re-encrypt and forward the message? Is that a way to go or is there any easier implementation? And if so, in what way you extract the IP from inside the .net code?

Comment: That's basically impossible. You can't know through which stages the connection passes, so obtaining the real IP is usually a futile task. You can use the `Request.UserHostAddress`what usually is the remote user address, but anyone can change that header.

Comment: Usually the real IP address is stored and relocated into another header (e.g. `X-Real-IP`) at proxy/load balancer level. You can then read this header as part of the request. Without detailed information about your load balancer and architecture it is impossible to answer this question.

Comment: hmmm  i see so there is not 1 way for all load balancers etc etc....okey i guess i will come back here with more info ? LB and architecture of the network is enough ?

Comment: Acutally this is mostly a simple "read the manual" case. Find out what load balancer, read the manual. Or, easier, put up a debugger and look at all the header fields you get. EIther you already get it from the load balancer, OR you need to enable it (hence the RTFM), but generally this is so trivial to research that it is not a programming question.